# Cannot install cocoapods 0.29

Tags: objective-c, jenkins, cocoapods

I successfully install cocoapods 0.29, and after attempting to run pod setup, it claims I must install 0.29.

Can someone please explain this to me??

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-0.29.0
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.29.0
1 gem installed
bash-3.2$ pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Already up-to-date.
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.29.0 - 
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
```

UPDATE:

After updating cocoapods, I am able to run pod setup, however still getting some error about 0.29 not being installed: (And also, when running pod --version, it says I'm on 0.22.3???)

```
bash-3.2$ sudo gem update cocoapods
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
bash-3.2$ sudo pod setup
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Already up-to-date.
Setup completed (read-only access)
bash-3.2$ pod install
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Already up-to-date.
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.29.0 - 
Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/claide-0.3.2/lib/claide/command.rb:210:in `rescue in run': undefined method `verbose?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
bash-3.2$ pod --version
0.22.3
```

Comment: Try to update again? I had the same error for another situation, updated using 'gem install cocoapods' and 'pod setup' just worked after that.

Comment: ok, great, that works, but now I have a new problem (My Jenkins integrated build process has been breaking because of this) ... updating the question with the result ...

Comment: what is the output of `type -a pod` ?

Comment: pod is /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod
pod is /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod
pod is /usr/bin/pod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

navigate this file and delete it

**/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/claide-0.3.2/lib/claide**

then open ur terminal add this

**sudo gem update**

its worked for me 100%

Comment: cannot load such file -- claide/argv.rb after install

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment

```
$ type -a pod
pod is /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod
pod is /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod
pod is /usr/bin/pod
```

it appears you have multiple installations of Cocoapods: one with `gem install cocoapods` in `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod` and another with `sudo gem install cocoapods` in `/usr/bin/pod` (I don't know what `/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod` is).

So running `gem install cocoapods` should fix the problem by updating the install in `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/pod`.

I'd recommend cleaning up your install though by removing either the global (with `sudo`) one or the local (without `sudo`) one.

**EDIT**:

Here's my Jenkins install:

Installed Cocoapods with `gem install cocoapods`.

Running `type -a pod` yield:

```
$ type -a pod
pod is /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/gems/bin/pod
```

In the Jenkins global config, I added the following environment variables:

```
GEM_HOME = $JENKINS_HOME/gems
GEM_PATH = $JENKINS_HOME/gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/
PATH = $PATH:$HOME/gems/bin
```

I added a "Shell script" build step to each project with:

```
POD_PROJECT_DIRECTORY='MyProject'  # Directory where the Podfile is. Probably the same as Xcode plugin's "Xcode Project Directory".

cd "$WORKSPACE/$POD_PROJECT_DIRECTORY"
# rm -rf ./Pods  # Uncomment this line if you want to re-download all the Pods each time
pod install --no-color
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help ... I ended up just removing the "Update Cocoapods" build step from my Jenkins integration since regardless what steps I take to fix cocoapods, I still get 0.29 required. And no matter what I do, it always says pod --version 0.22.3.  Very strange.

Comment: I updated the answer with my current working Jenkins config. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mismatch of version reported by 'pod --version' and what I was seeing when I updated to be mystifying.  Then I realized I had more than one ruby installed on my machine.  I changed my $PATH so that the ruby I needed to use came first (e.g. /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin):

In a new shell I found that 'pod --version' started reporting the '0.29.0' version I wanted.